# Using Tidy in JRuby

Tags: jruby

After spending some hours with the Ruby Debugger I finally learned that I need to clean up some malformed HTML pages before I can feed those to Hpricot. The best solution I found so far is the [Tidy Ruby interface](http://tidy.rubyforge.org/).

[Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) works great from the command line and also the Ruby interface works. However, it requires [dl/import](http://www.jbrowse.com/text/rdl_en.html), which fails to load in JRuby:

```
$ jirb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'tidy'
LoadError: no such file to load -- dl/import
```

Is this library available for JRuby? A web search revealed that [it wasn't available last year](http://markmail.org/message/gxyakwziya5yrggk).

Alternatively, can someone suggest other ways to clean up malformed HTML in JRuby?

### Update

Following Markus' suggestion I now use Tidy via popen instead of libtidy. I posted the code which pipes the document data through tidy for future reference. Hopefully, this is robust and portable.

```
def clean(data)
    cleaned = nil
    tidy = IO.popen('tidy -f "log/tidy.log" --force-output yes -wrap 0 -utf8', 'w+')
    begin
        tidy.write(data)
        tidy.close_write
        cleaned = tidy.read
        tidy.close_read
    rescue Errno::EPIPE
        $stderr.print "Running 'tidy' failed: " + $!
        tidy.close
    end        
    return cleaned if cleaned and cleaned != ""
    return data
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it from the command line from within [JRuby](http://jruby.codehaus.org/) with `%x{...}` or backticks.  You may also want to consider `popen` (and pipe things through it).

Not elegant perhaps, but more likely to get you going with minimal hassle than trying to mess with unsupported libraries.